# Launch RSS Reader via an Intent

Tags: android

I'd like to be able to launch the default RSS reader from my application.  Essentially, what we need is for the user to be able to press a button and the RSS reader is launched.

I believe the best way to do this would be with an implicit intent, but I'm not sure what code to use for the RSS reader.

I did something similar for contacts...

```
   Intent contacts = new Intent();
   contacts.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   contacts.setData(Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivity(contacts);
```

But I'm not sure what syntax to use for the RSS reader.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is a "default RSS reader" on many Android devices.

That being said, use `setDataAndType()`, supplying the MIME type of the feed in question (e.g., `application/rss+xml`), then hope for the best. `ACTION_VIEW` is as good a guess as any for an action to try.

You will then want to either catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` to let the user know there was no such activity, or use `PackageManager` to determine if there is a possible activity in the first place before calling `startActivity()`.